# Grunt Package cmd fail on Running minall task (ubuntu and windows)

Tags: linux, angularjs, gruntjs, npm, karma-runner

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute to get angularJS intalled on my OS but I'm stuck on this step :

```
# Build AngularJS:
grunt package
```

When I execute the "sudo grunt package" cmd, I get this :

```
Running "bower" task

Running "clean:build" (clean) task
Cleaning build...OK

Running "clean:tmp" (clean) task
Cleaning tmp...OK

Running "buildall" task
>> File build/angular-scenario.js created.
>> File build/angular.js created.
>> File build/angular-loader.js created.
>> File build/angular-touch.js created.
>> File build/angular-mocks.js created.
>> File build/angular-sanitize.js created.
>> File build/angular-resource.js created.
>> File build/angular-messages.js created.
>> File build/angular-animate.js created.
>> File build/angular-route.js created.
>> File build/angular-cookies.js created.
>> File build/angular-aria.js created.
>> File tmp/promises-aplus-adapter++.js created.

Running "minall" task
ERROR - Cannot read: Needed

ERROR - Cannot read: a

ERROR - Cannot read: revision

ERROR - Cannot read: single

4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Warning: Error minifying build/angular-animate.js Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I really don't understand what make minall fail...

I'm doing all of it because when a launch karma, I get this error :

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js 
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.24 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 38.0.2125 (Linux)]: Connected on socket bMZ0eWE4QWE4XZTs0cny with id 13199010
Chrome 38.0.2125 (Linux) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
  at /path/javascripts/app.js:1
```

Am I unlucky?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This problem/bug(?!) about difference with installing angular via `git clone` or `bower install`. By default grunt package taks try to use git command to detect current version and commit sha. But if you use bower -- this is not work and generate such warnings.

**There is my workaround:**

Find `./lib/versions/versions-info.js` and then go to `getBuid()` function.

```
function getBuild() {
  var hash = shell.exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD', {silent: true}).output.replace('\n', '');
  if (hash.code === 0) { // just check code answer as in other places
    return 'sha.'+hash;  
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: Thank youu ! It works now ! How did u find this one?

Comment: (I still get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
  at /path/javascripts/app.js:1", any Idea?)

Comment: @Adrien it looks like problem with your app that could not find angular. Withour listing it's hard to tell, but probably your app.js includes before angular.js?

Comment: mmh, at the end of my index.html, I got <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script> <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script> maybe I should open a new topic for that new mysterious problem :/

Comment: Okay, it was in my karma.conf, I wrote the agular.js path AFTER my app.js file :-) Thank you very much !